# Is it possible to add checkbox in button using gxt 2.5

Tags: button, checkbox, gxt

My Class extends gxt button and I would like to add a checkBox in the button
but there is no method for the addition of a component in button.

```java
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.Button;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.CheckBox;

public class ButtonCheckBox extends Button {

    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public ButtonCheckBox() {
        checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.setBoxLabel("CheckBox");

        setWidth(200);
    }
}
```

How can I, if possible, add a chckbox in my button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible using the GXT 2.x standard API, but may be achieved using an HTML `Template`.

Assuming the purpose of the checkbox is to serve as an indicator for the button state, i suggest you use a `ToggleButton` instead and modify its appearance. You can assign a CSS classname to it and apply differing background images according to its varying states:

```css
.my-toggle-button .x-btn-mc {
    background-image: url('images/toggle-button/checkbox-off.png');
}

.my-toggle-button.x-btn-pressed .x-btn-mc {
    background-image: url('images/toggle-button/checkbox-on.png');
}
```

#### References (on the GXT 2.2.5 API)

- [`Template`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/core/Template.html)
- [`ToggleButton`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/button/ToggleButton.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Eliran Malka and i done this using below code

```
import com.dips.pei.client.view.resources.Icons;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.ComponentEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.ToggleButton;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbstractImagePrototype;

public class CheckBoxButton extends ToggleButton {

public CheckBoxButton() {
    setIcon(AbstractImagePrototype.create(Icons.INSTANCE.notcheckedIcon()));
    setId("checkBoxButton");
}

@Override
protected void onClick(ComponentEvent ce) {
    super.onClick(ce);

    if(isPressed()){
            setIcon(AbstractImagePrototype.create(Icons.INSTANCE.checkedIcon()));
    }else{
        setIcon(AbstractImagePrototype.create(Icons.INSTANCE.notcheckedIcon()));
    }
}
}
```